# I want to make a sword that does no knock back

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a kit in Minecraft and I want to get a sword with no knockback.

**Is there a way to make that sword?**

Answer (score 2):

Items will always do knockback because all mobs have the ability to take knockback. If you uses any item (even your fists) and hit a mob they will take knockback. Therefore like Snafu_ said, it will be impossible to accomplish such a task with any item (not only a sword) unless you modify the mob taking the knockback (like adding a knockback resistance attribute).

Answer (score 1):

The only way you'll be able to achieve this effect is by giving the other players/mobs the knockback resistance attribute modifier.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible from what I understand, and I think it's actually a modifier to the sword. I'm not going to dig into it right now, but it may be possible.

A knockback of 255 could be the solution, because that is equivalent to nothing in most cases, but I don't recommend trying it in case it does launch you 29,999,999 blocks out.

Answer (score -4):

I believe if you get a sword with knockback 10,001 (With commands) then it will go into minus knockback. I haven't tested this myself so I am unsure if this method works.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this information?

Comment: Do you mean Level 65536? (either way, it's still wrong)